# swPrecache and CDN as proxy?

Tags: javascript, cdn, service-worker, sw-precache

I am using swPrecache, for loading my static assets of my PWA, to support offline mode. It working great. My setup is something like:

https://www.myexampledomain.com/myapp/ loads static index.html and which in turn loads uses swPrecache to load static assets like JS, Images, CSS,etc. Mind you these all are loaded from the same domain e.g www.myexampledomain.com/myapp/js/file1.js

But my swprecache list has decent number of files and takes some time to download on slower internet connection. FYI, I am already delaying the service worker registration to something like "load" event.

So here is what I am trying now. I need someone to validate if this is possible:

1. https://www.myexampledomain.com/myapp/ loads the static html files as before.
2. Have swPrecache intercept the static requests that go to app domain (e.g https://www.myexampledomain.com/myapp/js/file1.js) and instead fetch these to a CDN endpoint? (e.g https://some.cloudfront.com/myapp/js/file1.js).
3. Once downloaded the swPrecache continues to work as usual.

So essentially I am hoping to have swPrecache proxy the static asset requests, to a CDN to make it faster to download during the initial load.

Any comments/pointers on this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`stripPrefixMulti` option](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#stripprefixmulti-object) in `sw-precache` to change the URLs that are written to your service worker file. It's fairly brute-force, though, so it helps if there's a common prefix that is shared by all the assets that will be served from the CDN.

For example, if everything that will be served off of the CDN is stored in a local `assets/` directory, and their paths on the CDN will start with `https://my-cdn.com/assets/`, you can use

```
{
  stripPrefixMulti: {'assets/': 'https://my-cdn.com/assets/'},
  // ... other sw-precache options...
}
```

You'll want to make sure that whenever a local file changes as part of your build process the copy of the file on the CDN also changes immediately, or you'll run the risk of the versioning info generated for the local files being out of sync with what's on the CDN.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me. They way I understand stripPrefix/stripPrefixMulti is: during the build time, when creating the service-worker.js, it strips the specified prefix and replaces it with replacement string. What I am looking for is a way to specify a domain that can used to request/fetch the URLs. Looking at the service-worker.js, something equivalent to: `var request = new Request(cacheKey.replace(self.location.hostname,"my-cdn.com"), {credentials: 'same-origin'});`. This seems to work if I manually modify the service-worker. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What happened when you tried `stripPrefixMulti`? That's the closest you're going to get to your use case with `sw-precache`. The CDN-for-some-assets use case is a potential minefield, since your same-origin `sw.js` file and your remote-origin assets are necessarily deployed in two different steps, and any incomplete or delayed deployments could lead to stale content being cached indefinitely. So it's not something that I really want to make "easy".

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use

```
{
   stripPrefixMulti: {'assets/': 'https://my-cdn.com/assets/'},
   // ... other sw-precache options...
 }
```

but I'm sure you will face new CORS problem. I'm working on it too